# How to correctly save and read the image?

Tags: objective-c, image, path, save, nsuserdefaults

How to correctly save and read the image? After every update of the application version, the program wants to save new picture again.

saving image:

```
+(void)setImage:(UIImage*)image {

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imagePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.jpg"];

BOOL writtenToFile = [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imagePath forKey:key];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

reading image:

```
+(UIImage*)getImage {
NSString *imagePath = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key];
if (imagePath) {
    return [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]];
}

return nil;
}
```

Set Object in UserDefaults is always empty.

Answer (score 0):

Do not save the full path the image in the user defaults, because it contains a container GUID. 
This container GUID changes after an update.

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image {
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imagePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.jpg"];

    BOOL writtenToFile = [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:key];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

+ (UIImage *)getImage {
    BOOL imageExists  = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:key];
    if (imageExists) {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *imagePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.jpg"];

        return [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `NSUserDefaults boolForKey:` to check the stored value?

Comment: @rmaddy completely true, should have used `boolForKey:`

Comment: Also note that you have two variables named `imagePath` and one of them isn't a path at all. And its `BOOL` on Objective-C, not `Bool`.